# Prefiltering Kendo Grid from another view

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a flow chart that is showing different statuses of an item. When clicked on different parts bring the user to a view that is displaying a Kendo Grid. I am having trouble passing the value of the status to be filtered by so when a user clicks on a specific status, it is pre filtered by that already instead of showing item on the grid

This is how I have

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<T>()
                .Name("grid").Scrollable(c => c.Enabled(true).Height(1000))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Controller"))
                    .PageSize(20)
                    )
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Status).Width(150)
                    .Title("Status")
                       .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                               .Cell(cell => cell
                                   .ShowOperators(false)
                                   .InputWidth(150)
                                   .Operator("contains")
                                   .SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)
                                   .Template("statusFilter")
                               )
                           );
```

The .Template("statusFilter") in case it is relevant

```
 function statusFilter (element) {
        element.element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: {
                dataType: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("Status_Filter", "Controller")"
                }
            },
            optionLabel: "--Select Status--"
        });
    }
```

Filter in the controller

```
public ActionResult Status_Filter()
    {
        return Json(_itemService.GetItem().Select(e => e.Status).OrderBy(e => e).Distinct().ToList());
    }
```

Example of an asp-action that is directing to the grid.

```
 <a asp-action="KendoGridViewMethod" asp-controller="Controller" asp-route-status="Incomplete" id="incomplete" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-3x dashboard-icons"><span class="badge badge-info dashboard-badges"> @Model.Value</span></a>
```

Upon clicking a button on the flow chart (Incomplete for example), I want the user to be directed to the page with the Kendo Grid. With Kendo there are filtering options. I want the Kendo Grid to be pre filtered. I already have have some filtering modifications which is where the JSON had come in. I don't think that it is necessarily related, but I included it just in case.

Comment: You have to pass throw an url param (e.g. `MyView/?gridStatus=123`) and receive it in your action `ActionResult MyView(int gridStatus)`

Comment: That does work with normal tables, but that information is not making to the Kendo Grid. If I  'ActionResult MyView(int gridStatus)' in the Status_Filter it will only return Json information, which is is not very helpful.

Comment: You don't want to filter that JSON ? Use the status in that linq.

Comment: I do want the JSON, because that is how it is getting filtered in the `statusFilter`, but when I have `<a asp-action="MyViewMethod" asp-controller="Controller" asp-route-status="Incomplete" ` nothing is different, the URL is `MyView/?status=incomplete` and when I use `<a asp-action="Status_Filter" asp-controller="Controller" asp-route-status="Incomplete"` it just returns JSON page with all of the statuses.

Comment: Is not clear what you want to achieve, neither your whole scenario, code etc.. I can't figure how to help.

Comment: Upon clicking a button on the flow chart (Incomplete for example), I want the user to be directed to the page with the Kendo Grid. With Kendo there are filtering options. I want the Kendo Grid to be pre filtered. I already have have some filtering modifications which is where the JSON had come in. I don't think that it is necessarily related, but I included it just in case.